# Change admin user profile from temp

Tags: windows-7, windows

Can someone help me change the admin user account profile in Windows 7 to one that is not a temporary profile.

Somehow the password in my regular user account is not working and in the admin account it doesn't even show that there even is a password.

I try to create one but to no avail. It all gets deleted when I log out of admin. And the admin doesn't seem to give me the access I need to change the password like I have been able to with regular account profile in the past.

I have looked up how change admin user profile, but don't understand what I would have to do in order to avoid loosing only access I currently have to my computer

Comment: Is [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/38817-youve-been-signed-temporary-profile-fix.html) the problem you have ?

Comment: Enable the built-in Administrator account, change the password to the current Administrator user profile that isn't working, then disable the built-in Administrator when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

In your Admin profile open an Administrator Command Prompt by going to `C:\Windows\System32`, right click on `cmd.exe` and select Run As Administrator.

Now type `net user Joeitall Password /add`

This will add a user account called Joeitall with the password "Password" (you can change this to whatever you like)

Now type `net localgroup administrators /add`

This will add Joeitall to the administrator group.

Now restart your PC and sign in as Joeitall with your chosen password :)